# vscode settings pane is blank

Tags: visual-studio-code

For some reason, my vscode is no longer showing any settings in the UI settings pane. I can still open my settings.json, but even with my settings editor set to "workbench.settings.editor": "ui", I still get this:[image: settings photo]

I'm on macOS Catalina version 10.15.7 and vscode version 1.52.1

Any ideas on what might be causing this? Should I make a backup of my settings files and then reset the settings to default?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was having this exact same issue recently, so I was a little disappointed when there were no solutions. I did not have my settings editor set to "workbench.settings.editor": "ui",as you had, so I tried doing that, but after restarting vscode it didn't appear to do anything.

I've been working in the same folder for a while now, so I tried toggling to a different folder to see if somehow that would kickstart vscode into displaying the settings pane. That did not work, but when I toggled back to the folder that I was originally in, the settings pane was now populating with the normal settings for User and Workspace.

A little bit more troubleshooting and it seems like if I have the settings pane already open in the workspace when the workspace loads (either by toggling to a new folder or by restarting vscode), I can see the settings, but if the settings pane is not already open in a workspace and I try to open it, I get a blank page. I also noticed that the settings pane that appears when you load a fresh workspace is stuck on one tab (ie the settings don't change if you toggle between User and Workspace), but if I close and reopen the tab (not the whole workspace), it works as expected. Here's a gif to prove I'm not crazy:

[This is me just clicking around to show the behavior I'm describing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NkGx.gif)

I can't embed the picture because of my reputation, but hopefully that shows the behavior I am seeing. I wouldn't be surprised if at the end of the day this is still somehow my fault because of my settings or something, but hopefully this helps someone else.

**Small Edit**
Just wanted to point out that I acknowledge that this is not an actual solution to the underlying problem, but it's certainly worked well enough for me for now, maybe some one else can chime in with the true solution.

Comment: Wow, it worked! Thanks! I opened the UI settings page, quit vscode and reopened it and boom my settings are back!

Comment: Wow thank you... It worked. I am surprised at this strange bug..

Answer (score 0):

Most likely one or more of your extensions is blocking the menu pane from showing. Try disabling the most recently installed extensions one at a time to test menu pane.

My culprit was "VSCode Essentials" being an officially recommended extension, it is surprisingly poorly maintained.

Comment: i have no extensions (code doenst work, wont let me install then) and have the same whitescreen. Closing and reoppening worked arount it, but this is ridiculous; i use linux